How to dump the full internal storage disk contents (for running photorec)
A friend was copying files off her phone and deleting them to clear storage space, and accidentally deleted the entire DCIM/Camera directory.  This was done on the attached Windows PC (presumably via MTP), not on an app on the phone which might have a trashbin.
The phone is now shut off, and I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to simply dump the entire disk, similar to how you'd use dd on a Linux system.  I'd like to take a disk dump so that I can run photorec on the dump and hopefully get most of those photos back.  The problem: how to dump the bytes of the internal storage?  Unfortunately it's not like a PC where you can just pop the drive out, or boot from a live USB.
The device is a Moto G7 Play.
Approaches I have considered:

adb pull /dev/mmcblk0 -- as I understand, this requires root, and her phone is not rooted
Booting into recovery -- I tried this on my phone, and adb does not see the device, so I can't attempt to pull/do anything there.

I have never rooted a phone before, and the resources I've found so far are mostly just random .zip files, which seems like a great way to get infected with malware.  Also, I'm not sure if rooting will wipe the phone in the process, which would be counterproductive to what we're trying to do.

An image of the user data partition wouldn't help you as your phone uses File Based Encryption (FBE), thus all file data is encrypted. Therefore photorec will not be able to recover anything.

How to recover a deleted file from /data partition on a rooted phone?

Its not that simple. The drive contents are normally encrypted.
The photos are normally copied to the gallery. Search the gallery and copy them back.
